# /answers endpoint is error-500-ing against many sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

Just calling the "/answers" endpoint, no specific arguments, and I'm getting 500 errors:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=gaming

```
 {"error_id":500,"error_name":"internal_error","error_message":"this error has been logged"}
```

I didn't notice this on StackOverflow, but MSO is doing the same thing as gaming is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some indexes got applied unevenly, causing a few SQL queries to fail.

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.